# Is it more efficient to use a for loop?

Tags: javascript, performance

Here's an example of some code I have on my website... This actually goes on for another 12 iterations. Is it possible to use a for loop to do this? Is there a more efficient way?  Thanks!

```
document.getElementById("1").onclick=function(){
    lyre[0]=Number(!lyre[0]);
    document.getElementById("1").innerHTML=String(lyre[0]);
}
    document.getElementById("2").onclick=function(){
    lyre[1]=Number(!lyre[1]);
    document.getElementById("2").innerHTML=String(lyre[1]);
}
document.getElementById("3").onclick=function(){
    lyre[2]=Number(!lyre[2]);
    document.getElementById("3").innerHTML=String(lyre[2]);
}
 document.getElementById("4").onclick=function(){
    lyre[3]=Number(!lyre[3]);
    document.getElementById("4").innerHTML=String(lyre[3]);
}
```

Comment: As Dijkstra said, "Two or more, use a for."

Comment: @AaditMShah - And as L. Peter Deutsch said, "To iterate is human, to recurse divine."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At its most basic, you can do something like this:

```
function attachListener(lyre, lyreIndex, id) {

  document.getElementById(id).onclick = function() {
    // assign zero or one based on the current value:
    lyre[lyreIndex] = !lyre[lyreIndex] ? 0 : 1;

    // update the display of the value:
    document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = lyre[lyreIndex];
  }
}

for(var i = 0; i < lyre.length; i += 1) {
  attachListener(lyre, i, i + 1);
}
```

I've modified the code to be more idiomatically javascript. In general, you should avoid the primitive constructors (e.g. `Number` and `String`) and use the literal versions of the same.

There are other ways to make this more maintainable and idiomatic, but this should serve your need.

If you're worried about performance, a few dozen event listeners isn't usually something to be concerned with. If you are dealing with more than that, though, you should consider delegating your events. This limits the number of discrete event listeners while maintaining the same functionality:

```
document.getElementById('parent').onclick = function(e) {
  var node = (e.target || e.srcElement),
      index = node.id;

  if(lyre[index] === undefined) { return; }

  lyre[index] = !lyre[index] ? 1 : 0;

  node.innerHTML = lyre[index];
};
```

Where `parent` is the ID of some node in the document that all the elements share. [Here's a working JSBin](http://jsbin.com/UnANUPo/1/edit) that illustrates the concept.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible to use `for` to accomplish what you are trying to do. Although it won't be any better in terms of performance as you will execute a little bit of more operations, it's much better in terms of code organization. In most of the cases performance difference won't be perceptible, so I really suggest you use a loop for this.

```
function setEvent(index) {
    var id = index + 1;
    document.getElementById(id).onclick=function(){
        lyre[index]=Number(!lyre[index]);
        document.getElementById(id).innerHTML=String(lyre[index]);
    }
}

for (var i = 0, j = lyre.length; i < j; i++) {
    setEvent(i);
}
```

Comment: I didn't understand what you meant by refering to the same variable. Inside each function call, the `index` value takes the `i` value of the current for iteration. Here is it running: http://jsfiddle.net/bhAdH/

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I would spot a pattern, I'd create first of all a function. Then I would use a "for" (see the other answers how)... This will make my code well structured and easy to maintain.

But, as others said, it won't be any better in terms of performance.